# how to separate a text into lines

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a homework that wants us to take a text(sting) from user and separate it line by line ;
i have been thinking but I cannot get a right thing, I guess I need to use  pointers

For example:

```
Each shape has properties, AND //
each shape may be drawn with a//
different Char.
```

this text must be separeted from ( // )I need to find algorithm that give me the number of the lines is :3.

Comment: It is your homework. So, what have you done at home so far?

Comment: Count line endings.  Your teacher told you what a line ending looks like.  If you were not paying attention then google "c end of line character".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char *text = "Each shape has properties, AND //each shape may be drawn with a//different Char.";
    size_t len = strlen(text);
    char **separated_text = malloc(((len+2)/3)*sizeof(char *));
    char *p;
    int i, n=0;
    for(;;){
        if(p = strstr(text, "//")){
            len = p - text + 2;// 2 == strlen("//")
            separated_text[n] = malloc(len+1);
            memcpy(separated_text[n], text, len);
            separated_text[n++][len] = 0;
            text += len;
        } else {
            len = strlen(text);
            separated_text[n] = malloc(len+1);
            strcpy(separated_text[n++], text);
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i){
        puts(separated_text[i]);
        free(separated_text[i]);
    }
    free(separated_text);

    return 0 ;
}
```